# Counterexample about injectivity of preimage of a function

Tags: functions

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function between two sets. I am wondering if there is a case where $f^{-1}: \mathscr P(Y) \to \mathscr P(X)$ can not be injective ?

I feel like the fact that $f$ can only give one image to an element of $X$ makes it compulsory for $f^{-1}$ to be injective.

Many thanks

Comment: Notation: you should write $f : X \to Y$ and $f^{-1} : \mathscr{P}(Y) \to \mathscr{P}(X)$, $\mapsto$ has a different meaning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\{a\}$, $Y=\{1,2\}$, and $f(a)=1$. Then $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{a\}=f^{-1}(\{1,2\})$, but $\{1\}\neq\{1,2\}$.

More generally, $f^{-1}(B_1)=f^{-1}(B_2)$ if and only if $B_1\cap\mathrm{Im}(f) = B_2\cap\mathrm{Im}(f)$. Thus:

**Theorem.** Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a function. The inverse image function $f^{-1}$ is one-to-one if and only if $f$ is surjective.

*Proof.* Suppose that $f^{-1}$ is one-to-one, and let $b\in B$. Then $f^{-1}(\{b\})\neq f^{-1}(\varnothing) = \varnothing$, so $b\in\mathrm{Im}(f)$. Thus, $f$ is surjective.

Conversely, assume that $f$ is surjective, and let $B_1\neq B_2$ be subsets of $Y$. If $b\in B_1\setminus B_2$, then by the surjectivity of $f$ there exists $a\in X$ such that $f(a)=b$. Then $a\in f^{-1}(B_1)$, but $a\notin f^{-1}(B_2)$, so $f^{-1}(B_1)\neq f^{-1}(B_2)$. A symmetric argument holds if $b\in B_2\setminus B_1$. $\Box$